# Actual UIButton label font size for custom drawing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uilabel, font-size

I was wondering how I would be able to obtain the actual button label's font size that the text gets rendered with... not the one obtained through label.font. The reason I need this is because since I'm allowing for the button label's text to get resized based on the width of the button, the size therefore also changes. However this change isn't reflected upon in the label.font property. This value is needed because I basically draw the text myself (and set the default text to transparent), so I'd need to be able to get the actual font size so that the text I render fits the button's bounds. Thanks, and I hope you understood my question.